# How to use jquery to serialize to a certain element in a form

Tags: jquery, ajaxform

I want to serialize my form to post data ,
let say

```
<form id="myform" runat="server" >

    /* serialize this div element */

        <select class="form-control" id="depart" name="depart"  ></select>

        <select class="form-control" id="sel_blg" name="bldg"></select>

    /* end serialise this div element  */

    /* dont serialise this div element */
    <div class="collapse" >
      <select class="form-control" name="achead" id="Select5"></select>
      <select class="form-control" name="achead" id="Select5"></select>
    </div>
    /* end dont serialise this div element  */

<input type="submit" value="save data">
</form>
```

I tried using the following code

```
  var formData = $("#myform").not('.collapse:select').serializeArray();
```

But the above code is serializing all element.Please help

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var formData = $("#myform :not(.collapse select)").serializeArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with -

```
$("#myform").not('.collapse select').serializeArray();
```

Comment: i also tried    var formData = $("#myform").not(".collapse *").serializeArray();

Comment: it is serializing the whole form element. Yo can do it manually.

Comment: my form will change frequently ,this is the reason i want to use form serialization,please help

Answer (score 0):

**Try :**

```
$("#myform").filter('not:(.collapse select)').serializeArray();
```

Comment: not working ,giving error Unhandled exception at line 2, column 12714 in https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js

0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: not:(.collapse select)

Answer (score 0):

Your selector `$("#myform").not('.collapse:select')` selects the form, since you want to exclude some input elements, you need to select the input elements you want and then serialize them so

```
$("#myform").find(':input').not('.collapse:select').serializeArray()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to serialize that selects, don't set them attribute "name". Method serialize() or serializeArray() collects only that fields, which have attribute "name".